# Extracting an expiry date from a keytool certificate

Tags: bash, keytool

I am working on a fairly simple script to pull the expiry date from a keytool cert and compare this with todays date and then send a mail if that date is less than 30 days.  However where I am getting stuck is how to extract the expiry date using bash, I am running:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_301-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass <PWD> | grep "until:"
```

Which will output all the certs stored with multiple lines as follows:

```
Valid from: Tue May 26 01:00:00 IST 2015 until: Sun Jan 17 00:00:00 GMT 2038
```

The plan is to take the expiry (until) date from the line and convert that to epoch seconds and days to help calculate in the script.

Please can you suggest the best way for me to proceed.

Comment: I think you can write (with an update statement) your expected output of the overall process. Also, look the usage of [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) command; it might be useful to do such operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "days" in

> ... and convert that to epoch seconds and days

but to covert it to epoch seconds, you can first remove everything until "until: ":

```bash
UNTIL=$(keytool ... | grep 'until:' | sed 's/^.*until: //')
```

and then use `date`:

```bash
date -d "${UNTIL}" +%s
```

EDIT

Ok, for multiple entries in the keystore you can adapt the following snippet. Here we read alias and "until" date, so that we can identify with which certificate we work at each iteration. You can modify it to read other fields.

```bash
KEYSTORE=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
KEYSTORE_PW=changeit
while read -r ALIAS; do
    # ALIAS is in the form: "Alias name: <REST>". We want <REST>.
    ALIAS=$(echo ${ALIAS} | cut -d' ' -f3)

    # read the next line
    read -r UNTIL

    # UNTIL is in the form: "Valid from: ... until: <REST>". We want <REST>
    UNTIL=$(echo ${UNTIL} | sed 's/^.*until: //')

    # convert to epoch
    EPOCH=$(date -d "${UNTIL}" +%s)

    # do something with it
    echo "${ALIAS}  -->  ${EPOCH}"
done < <(keytool -list -v -keystore "${KEYSTORE}" -storepass "${KEYSTORE_PW}" | grep -E '^Alias name:|^Valid from:')
```

And the output is:

```
debian:ac_raiz_fnmt-rcm.pem  -->  1893456000
debian:accvraiz1.pem  -->  1924940257
debian:actalis_authentication_root_ca.pem  -->  1916306522
debian:addtrust_external_root.pem  -->  1590835718
```

Comment: This one is good but when I run this manually I only get one epoch timestamp, in my example there are around 20 certs e.g. 
until=$(keytool -list -v -keystore /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_301-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit | grep "until:" | sed 's/^.*until: //')
date -d "${UNTIL}" +%s
#date=date +%s
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $until
do
echo $line
done

lines like this are returned

Mon Nov 10 00:00:00 GMT 2031

Comment: @BurntFrets see my edit.

Comment: This solution seem entirely plausible, I am getting a syntax error on the last line:

keytoolexpiry.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
keytoolexpiry.sh: line 26: `done < <('keytool -list -v -keystore "${KEYSTORE}" -storepass "${KEYSTORE_PW}" | grep -E '^Alias name:|^Valid from:')'

If I can get this working, I would use further calculation to get the actual time and if that is less than 30 days

Comment: Are you sure you use bash? That's just [input redirection](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Input) and [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), it should work. Alternatively you can try to do it through a pipe: `keytool ... | while read -r ALIAS ...`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to extract the date as a string, which can be done using awk:

```
date=$(keytool -list -v -keystore /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_301-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass | grep "until:" | awk -F'until:' '{print $2}')
```

Then you can convert the string date into epoch using the date command:

```
epoch=$(date -d "$date" +"%s")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried this as well and not getting the epoch time when trying to pull each line in a for loop e.g.

certdate=$(keytool -list -v -keystore /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_301-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit | grep "until:" | awk -F'until:' '{print $2}')
epoch=$(date -d "$certdate" +'%s')

#echo $epoch

file=$certdate
date=date +%s
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $epoch
do
echo $line
done